# What is a good memory management strategy for precaching unbounded data set in Android?

Tags: android, performance, caching, memory-management

I am working on an Android app that deals with an arbitrary number of user-defined Views.  The Views can be very simple and lightweight, or they can be very complex and take a relatively long time to instantiate.

I want to use a background thread to precache some of these Views to improve responsiveness when the user switches from one View to the other.  I have a way to set priorities for each View to determine the order they should be added to the cache or removed from cache.

My problem is that I need to determine when I'm running low on memory.  I think I can use `MemoryInfo` to determine how much memory I have available.  But is there a good rule of thumb for setting thresholds?  At what point should I stop caching additional Views?  At what point should I consider removing lower-priority Views from the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've read, the memory limit I need to be concerned about is the Dalvik heap limit rather than the total memory available on the device. I use this process to get the current heap utilization:

```
Java.Lang.Runtime rt = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime();
long heapused = rt.TotalMemory() - rt.FreeMemory();
long heapmax = rt.MaxMemory();
double ratio = (double)heapused / (double)heapmax;
```

I pre-cache aggressively at low utilization ratios, and I clear the cache aggressively at high ratios.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is universal answer.

It generaly depends on how your UI is build, how you expect user to work with Views and how many Views can fit on screen (even if they are variable height).

You can see some template in how Android works with creating/pre-caching views in ListView/Adapter combination.

[AbsListView implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/AbsListView.java#AbsListView.RecycleBin.clear%28%29)

Comment: The user-defined Views in the app are all full-screen.  At most, you'll have two visible at a time during an animated transition.